# How to prevent out of memory exception while receiving big images from camera via usb cable?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, usb-otg

I'm using https://github.com/crazymaik/remoteyourcam-usb to connect Cannon camera to receive images via OTG cable (usb connection).

It works, but often when photos are taking fast or there was taken lot of pictures in sequence out of memory exception is thrown and app crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2147483659 byte allocation with 10640218 free bytes and 112MB until OOM
       at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:56)
       at com.somepackage.ptp.PtpCamera$WorkerThread.handleCommand(PtpCamera.java:631)
       at com.somepackage.ptp.commands.RetrievePictureAction.exec(RetrievePictureAction.java:64)
       at com.somepackage.ptp.PtpCamera$WorkerThread.run(PtpCamera.java:570)
```

Is someone used this library? Is there any way to prevent out of memory? Why so many bytes is trying to allocate (2147483659 - 2048MB)?

Logs:

- https://pastebin.com/Pi3VUcsn
- https://pastebin.com/Dmb9uNi6

EDIT: line where it crash: https://github.com/crazymaik/remoteyourcam-usb/blob/master/src/com/remoteyourcam/usb/ptp/PtpCamera.java#L631

Comment: you can re scale the received bitmap before displaying the image

Comment: I'm not viewing photo anywhere. I'm downloading photo from camera via usb connection and store in android app.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" this command inside the <application> tag in manifest might help you with it.

Comment: hello @dees91, is the library working fine? what camera model are you using to connect with that library, thanks